# What are benefits of using System. Diagnostics.Switch?

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I am trying to get into `system. Diagnostics` namespace and learning about it, but the first class I try to learn is `BooleanSwitch`.

I read about it in MSDN and I can't understand what the benefits of using this library really are. I tried to search on the internet but I am confused by what I saw in words and sentences that I do not understand like (trace, control debugging).

And there is a base class named `Switch` which `BooleanSwitch` inherits from and other class in this namespace.

Is there any website I can learn from about the `Diagnostics` namespace?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.switch is the abstract base class for the other switches. And BooleanSwitch's first line is: "Provides a simple on/off switch that controls debugging and tracing output."

Comment: It is unclear if you are asking about the `System.Diagnostics.Switch` class or the entire `System.Diagnostics` namespace/assembly; the question title suggests the former but parts of the body suggest the latter.  Also, why have you decided to start with the `Switch` class?  If you don't understand what it's for then how do you know you need to use/learn it?  What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: Mechanically these classes seem to do little more then put a reference wrapper around a bool. This class and it's followups where in the Standart and the original framework with 1.0 each. A fair number of classes that were added back then have been superseeded since then. Indeed, just take a look at all the non-generic collections that are still around: https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0006.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read about it in MSDN and I can't understand what the benefits of using this library really are.

The benefits of using this library are easily available diagnostic tools.  It is definitely a library worth using if you're looking to do some debugging with .NET.

> System.Diagnostics.EventLog
>
> This component provides functionality to write to event logs, read event log entries, and create and delete event logs and event sources on the network.
>
> System.Diagnostics.Trace
>
> Instrumentation allows you to monitor the health of your application running in real-life settings.
>
> System.Diagnostics.StackTrace & System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
>
> These classes will expose the stack information about the routines. Following example will return the name of the calling method.
>
> System.Diagnostics.Debug
>
> Provides a set of methods and properties that help debug your code. This class cannot be inherited. We all are accustomed to this class. Following are the important methods of this class.
>
> System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine  <<< this one is big

You can write to diagnostic logs, do traces.. these are extremely important for complex projects.  I'd say for simpler projects it might be a bit overkill, but it's definitely something you want to familiarize yourself with anyway.

Almost every library is going to be helpful in some context.  Libraries are pre-done work and the more relevant ones that you understand, the less work you will need to do.  MSFT libraries are usually very well documented and designed.

If you're looking for a good beginner guide, this would be a good place to start.

This is VB.NET but the general overview still applies:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/5358/beginning-system-diagnostics

I do agree that often the MSFT docs are hard to understand and implement.

EDIT: I just noticed that is a VB.NET (yuck) link so it would only be useful for theory and learning what the methods do.

The boolean switch just chooses whether or not to write an error message or not.  This could be useful in some situations where an exception is not thrown but your code has noticed some error in the data or some other code path has tripped a situation where you want to write to the debug log.

I don't think it's as useful as the general namespace is.  It might be useful in some niche situations but regardless of the switch; you'll want to learn this namespace anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As [hexagod said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58442192/10079572), the benefit is that it's a standard interface.

To address `Switch` and `BooleanSwitch` specifically, they are a way to define a named configuration value that you can set with the application's .config file.
You can have `System.Diagnostic.Trace.WriteLineIf()`* calls (or similar) conditional upon such a flag so they will not normally do anything, but can be "turned on" by changing the configuration file.  (So all of the diagnostic capability will be present in the released executable but inactive unless you need it.)

This is very similar to using `Properties.Settings` for the same purpose (the .config file in action) except you're defining the possible properties differently and they go into a different section -- `<system.diagnostics>` instead of `<userSettings>` -- and have to be configured manually (there's no equivalent to `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` for these).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-create-initialize-and-configure-trace-switches is a bit more descriptive than the documentation for the `Switch` classes.

*I'm referencing `System.Diagnostic.Trace` instead of `System.Diagnostic.Debug` here because I think it's better for the purpose.  They're mostly the same except calls to methods of `Debug` will be stripped out when you compile a Release executable while calls to methods of `Trace` will be left in but won't do anything unless you set up where to write to in the .config file.

Answer (score -2):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.switch?view=netframework-4.8)

> A switch provides an efficient mechanism for controlling tracing and debugging output at run time using external settings. The Switch class implements default behavior for switches, *allowing you to change the switch level at run time.* (emphasis mine - tymtam)

From the example from the same documentation

```
// Write a diagnostic message if the switch is set to entering.
Debug.WriteLineIf(mySwitch.OutputEnter, "Entering Main");

// Insert code to handle processing here...

// Write another diagnostic message if the switch is set to exiting.
Debug.WriteLineIf(mySwitch.OutputExit, "Exiting Main");
```

Comment: The question says "i read about it in MSDN" which would provide this same text as you're quoting here. It also says that they don't understand terms like "trace" and "control debugging".  It seems what's needed is an explanation of this documentation, not a repeat of it.

Comment: The OP has mentioned that they already read the documentation. So, IMO, simply quoting a part of it is unlikely to help them.